# INSERT/UPDATE with SELECT

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

> Members (Cols: memId, startDate)
>
> History(Cols: histId,memId, info)
>
> SubHistory(Cols: subHistId, histId, startDate, type)

I need to insert the SubHistory startDate on Members startDate with MS Access

I'm using the following code:

```
INSERT INTO Members (startDate)
SELECT sh.startDate
FROM ((SubHistory sh)
INNER JOIN History h ON sh.histId = h.histId)
INNER JOIN Members m on h.memId = m.memId
WHERE sh.type = 46 AND m.memId = Members.memId
```

Why is not working? Access keeps Asking me for Members.memId. Is there another way?
Not all Members have a start date.

Comment: Memid is not null at a guess, given you are inner joining on it, it muset be there in this case.

Answer (score 3):

When you examine the `SELECT` piece of that query, the `WHERE` clause is faulty ...

```sql
WHERE sh.type = 46 AND m.memId = Members.memId
```

At that point, Access can not use a data source named *Members* because you aliased it as *m* in the `FROM` clause.  And it can't resolve that name to *Members* in the `INSERT INTO Members` piece.

Therefore Access guesses `Members.memId` must be a parameter for which you did not supply a value, and then asks you to supply that parameter value.

So, in order for Access to understand you're talking about that field value, you would need to reference it with the alias instead of the table name.

However, if you make that change ...

```sql
WHERE sh.type = 46 AND m.memId = m.memId
```

... the condition, `m.memId = m.memId`, seems useless.  Perhaps you meant to refer to `memId` from one of the other tables.

Answer (score 1):

Is Members.memId the primary key for the Members table? (If not it probably should be). If it is then NULL values will not be permitted, so you'll need to pass this as part of the INSERT too.